# Seeking undelete votes, and some deletion insight for the sole answer to an old question

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, vote-to-undelete

[An answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47968225) ([screenshot for < 10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ayDT.png)) seems to have been needlessly deleted, and I'd like to call upon Meta patrons to help have it reinstated.

It was deleted over a year after it was posted, and is the only answer given to the question. I provided 3 solutions, some more out-of-the-box than others, and when the OP provided more detail, recommended one of them. I don't understand why it was deleted. Anyone got any ideas? True, it's not the most brilliant answer ever, but I've seen far worse. It's also my first deleted answer so I am curious about the process.

Comment: I see no reason to undelete it. The answer doesn't hold much in the way of value, and the question is a duplicate. The community would be much better served by marking it as a duplicate and moving on.

Comment: I was one of those people who voted to delete it and IMHO, felt it was more fit as a comment/steps for them to take (and VLQ), and it did not solve the question. Suggestions/steps to take are a different animal than answers/solutions. The other deleted answer was just a link for the OP to consult an external link and with an image sample. The possible duplicate left under the question which dates back to a time where answers as such were considered as acceptable, which no longer fits the bill today. The question was too broad and unclear, so not worth answering  IMHO and outdated.

Comment: I think duplicate link ( Convert SVG to image) is fine and voted as such. I don't think any of deleted answers are any better than ones on suggested duplicate

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thank you for seeing this and giving your point of view. I guess I disagree that suggestions/steps to take are not suitable as answers, they seem perfectly reasonable when the question is one of process or has a large amount of uncertainty about it, both of which applied to this question. Also, what makes are some questions worth answering and others not? Everybody needs help sometimes.

Answer (score 10):

Only one of the three bullets in your post is a **programming** suggestion, and it's awfully lacking in explanation. If you had the same problem as the asker, and found your anwer, would your search for information be complete? Would you know how to solve your problem? I'm dubious.

Does this mean the answer should have been deleted? Perhaps not. Should it therefore be undeleted? Not really; very little has been lost here. (It's also not a very good question, so perhaps leaving the whole thing to be autodeleted is best.) If you would like your answer to be undeleted, I suggest improving it by describing your programming suggestion with more detail than [a link to Wikipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968195/converting-svg-text-to-png-file/47968225#comment82905946_47968225).

Comment: *"... a link to Wikipedia."* - Maybe include a screenshot and about the "10 K" member thing (also) ;-)

Comment: You can see the comment in the screenshot I put into the question, @FunkFortyNiner.

Comment: Ah yes, I did see it. Just wondering if members that are less than 10K will click on the link in your answer and maybe say to themselves: *"What the...?"*, heh.

Comment: Fair point; I suppose the link to the comment really isn't worthwhile.

Comment: I don't think trying to expand "how to render HTML/SVG in headless browser" will be worth it - I believe we already have enough of similar answers on the SO.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Regarding "Only one of the three bullets in your post is a programming suggestion" — that's part of the point this answer sought to give: sometimes what the asker thinks is a programming question really isn't, and can have a non-programming answer. It was an effort to get people to think outside of the software dev box to solve their problem. I would have added more non-programming solutions if I could think of them!

Comment: This is a website for programming questions and answers. If the question isn't asking for a programmatic solution, then it's entirely off-topic, @NicholasShanks. And if the question _is_ looking for a programmatic solution, then your "outside the box" suggestions don't help.